# How does ASP.NET vNext compare to WinRT?

Tags: .net, windows-runtime, asp.net-core

ASP.NET vNext description in this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/03/asp-net-vnext-in-visual-studio-14-ctp.aspx) describes it as ‘a lean and composable .NET stack for building modern cloud-based apps’. Does that mean a similar limited subset of .NET like WinRT?

WinRT had serious limitations and breaking changes. It made porting popular libraries impossible because it [lacked the support for dynamic code emitting](http://geekswithblogs.net/mbrit/archive/2012/06/05/say-goodbye-to-system.reflection.emit-any-dynamic-proxy-generation-in-winrt.aspx). There were also many breaking changes in BCL (speaking from my own experience). I guess it was reasonable for a lot reasons but it took away a lot from .NET environment.

I don’t think ASP.NET vNext will have these limitations but it offers a lot more by claiming to be cross platform. It really sounds cool but I’m curious if we will get a similar experience like WinRT. Can I assume that we will work on the same BCL (relevant parts to ASP.NET vNext apps)?

There is also another statement that doesn’t say anything about supporting the old BCL:

> ASP.NET vNext will build on .NET vNext. .NET vNext is the next major
>   release of .NET Framework. .NET vNext will have a cloud optimized mode
>   which will have a smaller footprint as compared to the full .NET
>   Framework.

I am wondering if we will be able to upgrade our current applications and libraries seamlessly.

Comment: My understanding is that ASP.NET vNext is a web application and there is still a browser at the other end.   WinRT is more like a sandboxed .NET.  But only a comment.

Comment: There will be an upgrade path for MVC apps, but not Web Forms. Most developers will choose not to upgrade. There will be no need. IMO, ASP.NET vNext is all about squeezing as much out of Azure as possible.

Answer (score 0):

That "cloud optimized" is referring to the CLR used. ASP.NET vNext can target the Desktop CLR (as is today) and also the Core CLR (that comes with windows 8 on clients and windows 2012 on server) which is this smaller version (thus smaller memory footprint thus cloud optimized)

The ASP.NET vNext is said to support MVC, WebAPI, SignalR and so on. As about the System.Web well no one is stopping you from using the Desktop CLR and reference the System.Web and use WebForms while still using "K Runtime". It's just that ASP.NET vNext will no bring a new version of WebForms but will bring a new unified MVC 6 version(bringing together the MVC and WebAPI)